# iPhone - Prevent application download if no MapKit nor CoreLocation capability

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store, mapkit, core-location

I have an application that uses MapKit/Internet connection OR CoreLocation to make its job. I don't want users to be able to download (buy) the app if they do not have those both functions. Having one or the other would be ok.

What may I define in my project to prevent download from those users (if they exist) who don't have any of those functions on their devices ?

Comment: All iOS devices except for Apple TV have both functionalities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can specify a minimum OS if you are using functions that are not compatable with older OS's but any reasonably upto date device has those functions.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful using map kit, some features are new in 4.x like overlays, but annotations were avail in 3.x. You have to check in the usual ways if it's available before calling them.